# Can Samsung Remote Test Lab (RTL) work with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, samsung-mobile

I can load a device and run tests (load an app with the client) with Samsung Remote Test Lab, but I cannot get the Remote Debug Bridge to work with Android Studio.

adb connect localhost:xxxx says connected, but the device does not appear in Android Studio.

Has anyone gotten it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Samsung themselves. Works fine now.

Comment: Can you pls, give me the adb command. I tried, "adb connect 127.0.0.1", but connection refused.

Comment: got the same result. failed to connect to localhost and don't know why